# Colorizing an image in Swift

Tags: swift, core-image

I am trying to figure out some basic operations in working with Swift and images (PNG and JPG).

I have gotten to the point where I can successfully load a given image, but am unsure how to properly apply image adjustments that will stick.

Specifically I am trying to be able to trigger the following:

- colorize (HSB adjustment)
- invert colors

From the samples I could find online it seems most code samples are for objective C, and I've been unable to get anything working in my current playground.  It would seem from the documentation that I should be able to use filters (using CoreImage) but that is where I get lost.

Can anyone point me to or show me a valid (simple) approach that accomplishes this in Swift?

Many thanks in advance!

** EDIT ***

Here's the code I've got so far - working a bit better thanks to that link.  However I still run into a crash when trying to output the results  (that line is commented out)

So far all the examples I could find around the filtering code are objectiveC based.

```
import UIKit

var img = UIImage(named: "background.png")
var context = CIContext(options:nil)
var filter = CIFilter(name: "CIColorInvert");
filter.setValue(img, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)

//let newImg = filter.outputImage
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Google? "coreimage swift" gave me: http://www.raywenderlich.com/76285/beginning-core-image-swift

If this doesn't help, please post the code you've tried that didn't work.